# Page wraps on mobile is completely cutting of the top 90% of my page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I created a fiddle that shows how my page containers look on a desktop. However, now I am trying to edit my page for mobile.

I have done this many times and for some reason this is completely different. I can't even see the info on my page. Usually it is just completely stretched out or something normal like that.

The page doesn't allow me to scroll scroll up at all. It is only showing me the very bottom of my page and for some reason the gray container is coming up on the bottom in a horizontal manner.

I only adjusted this in my media query.

```
.page {
    width: 95%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 2.5%;
}
```

I have the viewport meta in the file I am mentioning.

Why is this happening?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rukymt5L/)

```css
html ,body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 font-style: Helvetica;
}
.page_background, .page {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.page_background {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#282828, #888888);
    /* Standard syntax */
}
.page {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 85%;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_background">
    <div class="page"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey can you please elaborate ( explain ) more about what is happening..?

Comment: The page is not allowing me to see or scroll to the top of the screen via mobile.

Comment: please https://jsfiddle.net/rukymt5L/1/ look at this

Answer (score 0):

For my CSS experience , you may use * { margin:0 auto; and padding:0px; }.the " * " symbol Applies that for every single tag.It is a good practice because some tags have different margin & padding by default.Also use " % " for your containers and if u want some of container to allow scrolling in devices with smaller screen just adjust the overflow:scroll;
Whatever , I can't understand your problem.Can you please explain us better.
Also if your text is going out of the container use min-width:value;.